# How to know an IPv6 address is configured stateful/stateless under Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

On macOS, I can rely on `IN6_IFF_AUTOCONF` (SLAAC) and `IN6_IFF_DYNAMIC` (DHCPv6).
https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.41.2/bsd/netinet6/in6_var.h.auto.html

On Windows, I have [`NL_PREFIX_ORIGIN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/nldef/ne-nldef-nl_prefix_origin) and [`NL_SUFFIX_ORIGIN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/nldef/ne-nldef-nl_suffix_origin) fields.

How can I know which configuration method (stateful/stateless) produced a particular IPv6 address on Linux? I didn't find any useful flags in `ifa_flags` field.

```
systemd-networkd v246

sysctl:
addr_gen_mode=0
use_tempaddr=2

global-unicast dhcpv6:
          dynamic            noprefixroute

global-unicast slaac privacy-extension:
temporary dynamic

global-unicast slaac eui64:
          dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute

unique-local dhcpv6:
                             noprefixroute

unique-local slaac privacy-extension:
temporary dynamic

unique-local slaac eui64:
                  mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
```

Comment: An IPv6 network interface can have many addresses. Are you asking "which address configuration methods this interface is configured to support?" or "which configuration method produced this particular IPv6 address?"

Comment: “which configuration method produced this particular IPv6 address?”

Answer (score 1):

For stateless, use the command:
`ip addr show dynamic`

For stateful, use the command:
`ip addr show permanent`

Quoting the ip-address man page:

```
  dynamic and permanent
          (IPv6 only) only list addresses installed due to stateless ad‐
          dress configuration or only list permanent (not dynamic) ad‐
          dresses. These two flags are inverses of each other, so -dynamic
          is equal to permanent and -permanent is equal to dynamic.
```

Comment: Did you test before answer? I cannot find any relationship between dynamic/permanent and stateless/stateful.

Comment: Yes some testing was done, although nothing exhaustive.  The quote from the ip-address man page seems to provide one relationship between stateless and dynamic.  From RFC4862 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4862) "Avoided the wording of "stateful configuration", which is known to be quite confusing, and simply used "DHCPv6" wherever appropriate.", which might explain why "stateful" is not mentioned in that man page.  There's a reasonable chance that I've interpreted your question differently than you intended.  At "new contributor" level I'm not able to ask for clarification before responding.